# Add data to parse table doesnt work (android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi im trying to add data to specific object in some table in parse.com this is the code :

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Buildings");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", building);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if(object == null) {
                Log.e("object","not found");
            }
            else {
                Log.e("object","found "+ object.getObjectId().toString());
                object.put("test", "test");
                object.saveInBackground();
            }
        }
    });
```

i debug the code and it was fine and he really find the object and it really add a column to the table with the name test but i dont see any value inside i just see all the time (undefined)

Comment: Don't see any values inside what?

Comment: dont see the value "test" in the object's row in the column "test"

Comment: Is the value of `ParseException e` being set to anything? Are you getting an error?

Comment: here is a link to picture of the parse table  http://www.interload.co.il/upload/8910878.png

Comment: and im not getting error , e is null

Comment: Are you sure the value of `building` is an objectId that is contained within the database?

Comment: I found the problem, it was ACL permissions I was need to enable write permission for all the users, thank you @cricket_007

Comment: Ah, cool. It's been awhile since I've used Parse, so I was out of ideas